# Mongoose ".select" option strange behaviour

Tags: select, mongoose

Here's my model:

```js
var Account = new Schema({
        username: String,
 likes: {
  users: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {}},
  reviews: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {}}
 },
 requests: {
  incoming: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {}},
  outgoing: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {}}
 }
}, {minimize: false});
```

Here's my request:

```js
router.get('/requests', function(req, res, next) {
 var id = req.user._id;
 var callback = function(err, doc){
  if(err) {
    next(err);
    return;   
  }
  res.send(doc);
 }
 Account.findById(id)
  .select({requests: 1})
  .exec(callback)
})
```

Here's my result:

```js
{
  likes:{},
  requests: {
    incoming:['a','b','c'],
    outgoing:['d','f','g']
  }
  _id: 'KAJDiasjdaiodjwoi43j034345'
}
```

Why does "likes:{}" show up?